# jquery validation plugin - validate only first filed

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Using jquery with validation plugin

Here is some code:
http://jsfiddle.net/WKXn2/7/

I can't figure out why:

1. When clicking submit button validation is done only opon first filed with any validation class. If it's ok it passes even when other fileds are not valid. In this example it stops only on a 3rd filed.
2. Why does "name" rule not work?
3. Why does required rule not work when added to email rule?

Answer (score 1):

You have some errors in your code.

Try this:

```
     $().ready(function() {

            $("#myForm").validate({
                 rules: {
                      required: {
                           required: true
                      },
                      email: {
                           required: true,
                           email: true
                      },
                     name: {
                         required: true
                     }
                 }
            });
       });
```

And also, you do not have any method on your form.
You can find the documentation here regarding the rules and options
http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: Nope. Try it on jsfiddle. You have change only "document ready" part, so how could it fix anything? There's no need for setting method just to do the js validation before submitting a form.